# How to reference a child array based on the parent array's key?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following dictionary:

```
var deckDictionary = [
            "card1": ["ace","hearts"],
            "card2": ["ace","spades"],
            "card3": ["ace","diamonds"],
            "card4": ["ace","clubs"],
]
```

What I want to do is set `cardSuit2` to be equal to the 2nd object in the array with key `"card2"` like so (pseudo-code):

```
var cardKey2 = "card2"
var cardSuit2 = whatever the card suit value is at cardKey2 ([[deckDictionary[1]][1]]?)
```

So for instance in this case, `cardSuit2` would be equal to the 2nd object in the array with key `"card2"`, so `"spades"`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: @Wain I tried `var cardSuit1 = ([[deckDictionary[1]][1]])`, and it gives me an error stating `Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Array<String>]' with an index of type 'Int'`

Comment: @ghobs91what about var cardSuit1 = deckDictionary["card2"]![1]

Comment: @ghobs9 Just make sure that you are indexing the dictionary with a key you know will exist. If that is not the case, you'll need to check if deckDictionary["card2"] is nil.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get the value of the element that is pointed out in the question it is possible to do so:

```
var cardKey2 = "card2"
var cardSuit2 = deckDictionary[cardKey2]?.last
```